# IIS/Apache dont recognize my certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, tomcat, ssl-certificate

Im completely new in this. I have a windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS 7.0 with a expired certificate, so  finally i created another (*.CSR, then PKCS#7 and installed).

Installing the certificate i have a problem but solved following the [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959216/en-us). So now i have my certificate active and installed in my server.

Now i go to Bindings in my default web site, modify my "https://" binding and change the anterior certificate for the new. Finally i deleted the expired certificate and only i have the correct and active certificate, but when i enter in my server from another browser only shows the expired certificate and appears an SSL warning.

What i need to do? i tried to search in my Apache Tomcat 7.0 some reference to SSL/Https but i cant find anything. I need to change something in Tomcat?

Thank you in advance (and for your patience with a newbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

In our system we have two Virtual Machines with IIS, i installed the certificate in the other and now it works perfectly (i dont needed to modify Tomcat).